# Palm Pre not picking up embedded YouTube videos

Tags: drupal, youtube, palm-pre

I've embedded a YouTube video onto a site (built in drupal) using the embed code from the video's YouTube page.

If I visit that page on an iPhone, it picks up the fact that there is a YouTube video and displays the icon that you click to pop open the video and watch it.

If I visit the same page on a Palm Pre it just displays a blank space where the video should be.  If I visit the video on the YouTube page itself, however, the Palm Pre picks up the fact that there is a video and allows you to open it.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has run into the same problem and has some insights they can offer.  I'd love to have a more graceful solution than just adding a link to the YouTube page below the embedded player

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the embed code actually *used* on the YouTube page (as opposed to the one they offer for quick copy & paste) with the one you are using, as there are quite some different ways to embed a video.

I would expect them to use the [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Embedding) for embedding, which is a tiny bit more effort to use on your page, but usually works a lot more reliable than the 'old fashioned' embed tag offered for quick copy&paste.

You might also try requesting the YouTube page faking the user agent of the Palm Pre, as they might deliver something different for those, but that is pretty unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer, I will explore this option